# Why does a URL shared on Facebook return 0 shares in the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have several examples of URLs that have been shared on Facebook, but when I retrieve the engagement numbers via Graph API a share count of 0 is returned.

Original link: https://ejournal.undip.ac.id/index.php/jitaa/article/view/11730

Posting on FB: [posting](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=790084137845947&id=583799085141121)

Engagement via Graph API:

```
{
  "engagement": {
    "reaction_count": 0,
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 0,
    "comment_plugin_count": 0
  },
  "id": "https://ejournal.undip.ac.id/index.php/jitaa/article/view/11730"
}
```

I can look up more examples if that helps, but I was wondering if anyone knows why and when shares of URLs are counted.